# Is there a column option to display additional pivot fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a `belongsToMany` relationship with a pivot timestamp field which I have configured for creation and update as mentioned within the documentation:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-how-to#extra-saving-additional-attributes-to-the-pivot-table

```
        CRUD::field([
            'name' => 'statuses',
            'type' => 'relationship',
            'subfields' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'achieved_at',
                    'type' => 'datetime',
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

Is there an option to also display additional pivot "subfields" when using column for the show requests?

I tried adding subfields to the column definition but this results in the same result. The documentation only mentions pivot attributes on `CRUD::field()`.

```
CRUD::column('statuses')
    ->type('relationship')
    ->subfields([
            ['name' => 'achieved_at', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => __('Achieved at')],
    ]);
```